# Tkinter destroy() freezes window, rather than closing it until the program terminates?

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, tkinter

So I've been having problems with Tkinter for Python 3 on MacOS 10.15.5. Here's the reproducible code for my system:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as msgbox

def quit():
    root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()

lbl = tk.Label(root,text="This is a label.")
ent = tk.Entry(root)
btn = tk.Button(root,text="Quit", command=quit)

lbl.pack()
ent.pack()
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
for i in range(800000):
    print(i)
```

After I press "quit", the for loop runs in the background, but the Tkinter window freezes (with the spinning wheel), until the for loop concludes. I'm trying to create a program that takes user input at the beginning and then runs code in the background, so you can see why I'd rather not have the GUI frozen the whole time.

I'm running this code from the terminal, but I get the same issue using IDLE. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling several different versions of python (from the python website, since apparently that's the way to use Tk properly), and this problem persists.

Weirdly enough, I've seen that adding an *input* statement, rather than any other code, immediately after the `mainloop`, will cause the window to close, but I can't figure out why, and it wouldn't really work with my broader program.

Comment: I should add this code works perfectly fine with built-in python 2, but the rest of my program cannot run on python 2.

Comment: I think there is quit() as build-in method and that causes problem, can you skip that part and write your button like this `btn = tk.Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.destroy)`. Or change your method name

Comment: Try adding `root.update()` immediately after `root.mainloop()`, to give it one final chance to respond to the closing of the window.  `input()` helps because Python somehow arranges for the underlying readline function to call `update()` for you - if it didn't do this, you couldn't experiment with Tkinter in interactive mode, as the GUI would be frozen.

Comment: @sTekin even when I make that change the same problem exists.

Comment: @jasonharper, this causes an error to be thrown (trying to call ```update``` on a window that's already been destroyed. I tried your suggestion but swapped ```destroy``` with ```root.quit()```, and the same problem still occurred. Maybe it's a macOS issue?

Comment: Its works well for me. You can try to make a variable `running` put at `True`, put `root.update` in a `while running:` loop instead of `root.mainloop()`, and put `running` at `False` (add `global running` just before) when you click the button. And at the end of your code, add `root.destroy`. I can put this comment more clearly in the answer place if you don't understand.

Comment: @D-00 I actually tried this exact fix before, and it still gave the same error. For now I'll just use ```iconify``` just before ```destroy``` because that's working well enough for me.